# Passing Values from HTML page to flask app for Data Base connectivity

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on project and I am trying to pass on the Database username and Database password from an HTML page user input to the flask database argument
here is what I am try to do

```
# Flask Code

from flask import Flask
from flaskext.mysql import MySQL

app = Flask(__name__)

DB_USERNAME = str(request.form['username.db'])
DB_PASSWORD = str(request.form['password.db'])
mysql = MySQL()
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_DB'] = 'database'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_HOST'] = 'localhost'
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_USER'] = DB_USERNAME
app.config['MYSQL_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] = DB_PASSWORD

mysql.init_app(app)

@app.route('/')
def someName():
      cursor = db.cursor()
      sql = "SELECT * FROM table"
      cursor.execute(sql)
      results = cursor.fetchall()
      return render_template('index.html', results=results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug=True)`
```

and There is the HTML code

```
<form class="form-inline" action="/app.py">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="user">DB USER NAME:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username.db">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="pwd">DB PASSWORD:</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password.db">
</div>
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" type="submit">Connect</button>`
```

but this is not working, please suggest how I can make this work

Comment: `action="/app.py"` ??..What is this?..Shouldn't be just `action="/ "` ?

Comment: Yes...sorry that was a mistake